# Is there a nicer way to set POST body data in rspec on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

Than `request.env['RAW_POST_DATA'] = json_body`?

Comment: Is this for a controller spec? It would help if you could include an example.

Comment: Sorry, yes, it's for an rspec controller test.

Comment: Not as far as I can tell.  Thanks for showing me how to set the raw post data though :)

Answer (score 11):

I'm not sure if this is what you mean, but you can set the request headers to indicate JSON:

```
  describe "POST 'create'" do
    it "should be successful" do
      request.env["HTTP_ACCEPT"] = "application/json"
      post 'create', :article => { :title => "Foo" }.to_json
      response.should be_success
    end
  end
```

Comment: Interesting, but we'll need to set the .json suffix for our API documentation but I guess we can do it this way as well.

Comment: Why do you set the second `post` argument to be `:article => <a hash>.to_json` rather than just a straight-up json string like `<a hash>.to_json`?  Does this require your handler to decode the contents of the article param rather than decoding the body?